# Lua Control Statments having odd behavior

Tags: if-statement, lua, lua-table

I'm getting a very unexpected result from what should be basic control statement operations. I have the following, a file being read with this sort of data:

```
1, 51, one , ab
1, 74, two , ab
0, 74, tree , ab
0, 74, for , ab
0, 74, five , ab
```

My snip of Lua code that processes it:

```
if file then
for line in file:lines() do
LineArray = line
CanClaimInfo[LineArray] = {}
lineData = utils.split(line,",")
    if lineData[1] == "0"  then
        lineData[1] = "CAN A"
    elseif lineData[1] == "1" then
        lineData[1] = "CAN B"
    else
        lineData[1] = lineData[1]
    end
CanClaimInfo[LineArray]["CANBus"] = lineData[1]
CanClaimInfo[LineArray]["Address"] = lineData[2]
CanClaimInfo[LineArray]["Name"] = lineData[3]
end
```

and I get this as an output:

```
CAN A   74  for
CAN A   74  tree
CAN A   74  five
CAN B   74  two
1       51  one
```

I don't get how it slips through the `elseif lineData[1] == "1" then` bit. I checked and there are no lead/trailing white spaces or anything like that. Any ideas?

Comment: So I just realized that the split function I'm using which is the same as what Henrik Ilgen linked is for LUA version 5.1 and I'm currently using 5.2. I'm suspecting this is the source of my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe utf-8 encoding bytes at the beginning of file? Try printing lineData[1] before the "if" tests to see what it is, and `print(#lineData[1])` to see how many chars it has. Likely more than 1 char so it ends up in that third branch (else):

```
lineData = utils.split(line,",")
print(#lineData[1]) -- likely prints 1 for all but first line
if lineData[1] == "0"  then
```

To find the extra bytes, try `print(string.byte(lineData[1], 1, #lineData[1]))`.

Comment: I also think it some encoding bit hidding but I've tried printing lineData[1] out directly and I can't seem to find any evidence of any.

Comment: but just printing the lineData[1] may not reveal it, did you print its length?

Comment: So I used this line right after the "end" of the if statement. "lineData[1] = string.gsub(lineData[1], "(%w+)", function(w) return string.len(w) end)" it prints 3 1 (CAN #) for all line data entries and 1 for the first line address 51. Which would make me think there are indeed no trailing items.

Comment: @Nimjox for sure it will print that because by then the substitution has already been missed. Why not just `print(#lineData[1])`, and do it *before* the if block so you see the unprocessed data? Output should be 1 for all lines, except perhaps first, if that's the case you know where to dig.

Comment: @Nimjox That's counting word characters. That's going to ignore exactly the sort of non-word encoding characters the OP was asking about. Don't play games getting the count just ask lua for it. Try `linedata[1] = linedata[1].."("..#linedata[1]..")"`. I expect you may get four.

Comment: !!! You guys nailed it. THANK YOU SO MUCH. I returned #lineData[1] directly and got all 1's and 4 for the first one. ER do you have any idea what those leading bits might be?

Answer (score 2):

Hm, seems like your utils.split function has some problems. I used a function from http://lua-users.org/wiki/SplitJoin and it works quite well with your code:

```
utils = {
    split = function(str, pat)
       local t = {}  -- NOTE: use {n = 0} in Lua-5.0
       local fpat = "(.-)" .. pat
       local last_end = 1
       local s, e, cap = str:find(fpat, 1)
       while s do
          if s ~= 1 or cap ~= "" then
         table.insert(t,cap)
          end
          last_end = e+1
          s, e, cap = str:find(fpat, last_end)
       end
       if last_end <= #str then
          cap = str:sub(last_end)
          table.insert(t, cap)
       end
       return t
    end
}
```

Maybe your function converts the 1 to a number (for whatever reason). In Lua, `"1" ~= 1`!

Comment: I have that exact split function, line for line. I also tried with "or lineData[1] == 1" to catch numbers no luck.

Comment: this can't be the problem because it only fails for the first line  (address "51")