# Lua string split for 5.2

Tags: string, lua, split, lua-table

I'm having some trouble with what I believe is this commonly used string split function for 5.1:

```
utils = {
split = function(str, pat)
   local t = {}  -- NOTE: use {n = 0} in Lua-5.0
   local fpat = "(.-)" .. pat
   local last_end = 1
   local s, e, cap = str:find(fpat, 1)
   while s do
      if s ~= 1 or cap ~= "" then
     table.insert(t,cap)
      end
      last_end = e+1
      s, e, cap = str:find(fpat, last_end)
   end
   if last_end <= #str then
      cap = str:sub(last_end)
      table.insert(t, cap)
   end
   return t
end
}
```

I'm using Lua version 5.2 and I was wondering if anyone has or knows of a string split function for 5.2, or if they could confirm or deny if this code would experience problems running in 5.2? Here's a link to my original problem for [reference.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21127135/lua-control-statments-having-odd-behavior)

Comment: I believe you have mis-diagnosed the problem. See my comment on Schollii's answer to your other issue (and their most recent comment too which says the same thing as mine).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There will be no issues with that split function, from my POV.

note comment will be added, because of old(5.0) table length syntax. 
http://www.lua.org/pil/19.1.html

There was nothing, that can cause an error in such split implementation( It's known utility function, and I used in in multiple 5.2 projects, never have any problem's)

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer and concluded that there is no issue using this 5.1 utility in 5.2. Thanks for the input.